# Comparator in Linked List declaration

Tags: linked-list, comparator

Hi I can't compile my code when I use comparator in Linked List declaration. Can you tell me what is wrong in this?

```
List<Integer[]> eventLst = new LinkedList<Integer[]>(new Comparator<Integer[]>()
 {
    @override
    public int compare(Integer[] arr1,Integer[] arr2)
    {
        return arr1[0]-arr[1];
    }
 });
```

Comment: Do you really mean this to be a list of integer arrays?

Comment: In `compare`, you use an undefined variable `arr`. Moreover, if this is not the error, could you show the compilation errors ?

Comment: @Scott : Yes its a list of Integer Arrays

Comment: @pierre : this is the compilation error

Comment: The constructor LinkedList<Integer[]>(new Comparator<Integer[]>(){}) is undefined